# USB Filter on windows embedded 8 standard

Tags: windows, windows-embedded-8

I am using windows embedded 8 standard and I want to use USB Filter introduced in windows embedded 8.1 industry, is there a way to install this feature on windows embedded 8? I have the ELM installed but I can't find a way to add a USB Filter.

Is there a way?

thanks.